# Selenium check dynamic elements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium/Java

the task is to get text of two possible elements: elem1 and elem2. 
When Scenario A - elem1 is displayed, and the locator of elem2 doesn't exist. And vice versa.

My code:

```
 public void checkTextInPopUp() {
    List<WebElement> commonDiv= driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//* 
[@id='CheckStockProductAvailabilityWidget']/div/div"));

    if (commonDiv.size()>=1) {

        addToCartStock.click();         

    } else {

System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("ajaxErrorMsg")).getText());
        closeCheckStock.click();            
    }
}
```

My code is always work only in scenario1 and failed when element2 is dispayed, saying: unable to locate element2.

Elem1 html:

```
    <div id="CheckStockProductAvailabilityWidget" class="dijitContentPane" 
lang="en" controllerid="CheckStockProductAvailabilityController" 
widgetid="CheckStockProductAvailabilityWidget" 
dojotype="wc.widget.RefreshArea" style="">
      <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="span11">
            <p id="ajaxErrorMsg" class="error-font-color">Price & 
Availability Check cannot be executed for your order.</p>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Elem2 html:

```
<div id="CheckStockProductAvailabilityWidget" class="dijitContentPane" 
lang="en" controllerid="CheckStockProductAvailabilityController" 
widgetid="CheckStockProductAvailabilityWidget" 
dojotype="wc.widget.RefreshArea" style="">
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span11">
    <div class="row-fluid ">
       <div class="span12">

              Part# 00000
             <br/>
             <p>
        </div>
      </div>
  <div class="row-fluid space-bottom">
  <div class="row-fluid ">
  <div class="row-fluid mobile-inline-block">
```

Both elements have a common , and both returns "1" when getting element.size

Comment: Whether you want to extract the "Price & 
Availability Check cannot be executed for your order" text from element 1 and " Part# 00000" text from element 2 html?

Comment: something like: if ("Price & Availability Check cannot be executed for your order".isDispayed) { do this} else { get text of element "Part# 00000". but when first text is displayed, another one (Part# 00000") doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay. So,I have assumed,  At any point of time, we can see either element 1 html or element 2 html and updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the code as below

**Code:**

```
    public void checkTextInPopUp(){

        WebElement rootElement=driver.findElement(By.id("CheckStockProductAvailabilityWidget"));
        List<WebElement> element1List=rootElement.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='span11']/p"));

        if (element1List.size()==1) {
            ---Do your stuff----
            addToCartStock.click();
        } else {
            System.out.println(rootElement.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='span12']")).getText());
        }
    }
}
```

**Details:**

1. Find the Root WebElement. Since, this element always visible in both element 1 and element2 HTML
2. Element 1 may or may not be visible at a time. To avoid `NoSuchElementException`, find the element using `findElements` Method and store the element in List (You can find the element using the root element)
3. If the element 1 is **found**, then element 1 will be visible and element1 size will be 1.
4. If the element 1 is **not found**, then element 2 will be visible and
   element 1 size will be 0.

   5. logic can be added based on the element size condition

**Updated Code:**

```
List<WebElement> elementList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p[@id='ajaxErrorMsg']"));
//If the element 1 html is present, then element list size will be 1, else it will be 0.
if(elementList.size()>0){
    //element 1 related stuff
    ---Do your stuff----
            addToCartStock.click();
}
else{
    //element 2 related stuff
    System.out.println(rootElement.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='span12']")).getText());
}
```

Comment: the size of the rootElement is always 1, so it will always execute statement after if and will ignore else.

Comment: No. I haven't taken the root element size. Using the Root Element, I am getting the element1 in List( Xpath --> ".//div[@class='span11']/p" ).It's called Chained Search. If the Element 1 is available, then element1List.size() will be 1, else it will be 0.  This code will work without any issue

Comment: @Y_Sh: I have updated the details in the answer. Please check

Comment: the element1 with Xpath --> ".//div[@class='span11']/p isn't the one element to be taken. Once element 2 is displayed the element1 will not be existed. And I need to use both elements in one condition: if element 1 is displayed do this, else take element2 text and do this.

Comment: yeah.I think, you are not getting my point. The element 1 is getting displayed inside the span11 class with tag as P.But In Element 2 HTML, P tag is not present inside the div tag[Span 11 class] . Have you tried with the above code?

Comment: Yes, I did. And it works only when element1 is displayed. But failed when element 2

Comment: Oh. Actually, the above code should work. However, you can try with the modified code

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the solution by using try and catch. Will see if it's an ideal one.

```
public void getStockPopUpMessage() {

    try {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ajaxErrorMsg']"));
        System.out.println("Stock displays: " + 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ajaxErrorMsg']")).getText());
        closeCheckStock.click();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("No ajax");
        dothis();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use
@FindAll ({
@FindBy(locator elem1)
@FindBy(locator elem2)`enter code here`
})
private WebElement elem`enter code here`X;

FindAll annotation works with OR logic. It will find elem1 or elem2 and store  it as a web element. Alternatively you can store it in a List of web element within your object repository.